# Quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a separated scheme, $F$ an abelian sheaf on $X$ in the Zariski topology.

> In order to assign an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure on $F$, is it enough to do it on a **single** open affine cover of $X$, compatibly with pairwise intersections?

Or is it necessary to assign the $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure on **every** affine open of $X$, compatibly with restriction maps?

Comment: Hint: Consider the special case where $X = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is an affine scheme and $F$ is an abelian sheaf on $X$. Does an $A$-module structure on $F(X)$ uniquely determine an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure on $F$?

Comment: Is not so difficult to see that between all the possibles $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structures for $F$ compatible with the structure you fixed on the cover, there is one and only one that is Quasi-coherent. Maybe that was your original question (I think so because of your title).